# why am I getting a 404 when looking for the id of an object django

Tags: python, django

I cannot get the liftview to work, the test page is working fine. Am I missing an import into the views? I have data in the database with an id of 1 (picture included to show).

```
#polls/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test', views.test, name='test'),
    path('<int:lift_id>/', views.liftview, name='liftview'),
]



#views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse


def liftview(request, lift_id):
    return HttpResponse("lift id")

def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("test")


#models.py   
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Lift(models.Model):
    lift_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lift_name
```

Traceback:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/liftview
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
polls/ [name='index']
polls/ test [name='test']
polls/ <int:lift_id>/ [name='liftview']
The current path, polls/1/liftview, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

there is data w/an id of 1..

[image: database contents]

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/`. You don't have any URL configuration that ends with `/liftview`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `polls/urls.py` you have defined your path as

```
path('<int:lift_id>/', views.liftview, name='liftview'),
```

Therefore, you can access this path by going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/` and not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/liftview`

If you want to access this path on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/liftview`  then in your `polls/urls.py` change the `path` to

```
path('<int:lift_id>/liftview', views.liftview, name='liftview'),
```